# Binding Routes to a main file

Tags: node.js, routes

I am building an application using nodeJS and angularJS. I have different routes belonging to different groups. Is there a way I can mention routes belonging to different groups in seperate files and import them into main server js file and use the methods directly from the main server js file?
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am binding my subroutes file using `require('./ subroutes.js')` in the main server js file. And in the subroutes.js, I am encapuslating my routes in `module.exports = function(app){
//write your routes here
}`
Another important thing here is that if your subroutes needs any variables set from server.js file, then you need to include 'server.js' in subroutes.js file as below

```
var file = require('./server.js');      
module.exports = function(app){
    //write your routes
   //If you need to use variables from server.js, use file.variablename wherever needed.
    }
```

This works!